# Incorrect confirmation link received on e-mail in magento 1.9 custom module

Tags: php, email, magento

I have installed a custom blog module on Magento 1.9 and when a user leaves a comment to a post, the administrator will receive an e-mail with a link to a page where he can approve or disapprove the comment. The link is incorrect and I can't figure why. This is the code where the link is created:

```
if (Mage::getStoreConfig('blog/comments/recipient_email') != null && $model->getStatus() == 1
            && isset($commentId)
        ) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            try {

                $adminUser = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('admin/routers/adminhtml/args/frontName');

                $data["url"] = Mage::getUrl("awblog_manage_comment/edit/id");
                $data["url"] = str_replace("index.php", $adminUser, $data["url"]);
                $data["url"] .= $commentId."/";

                $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                $postObject->setData($data);

                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        Mage::getStoreConfig('blog/comments/email_template'),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig('blog/comments/sender_email_identity'),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig('blog/comments/recipient_email'), null, array('data' => $postObject)
                    );
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
            }
        }
```

When I echo the $data["url"] on my local server I get the correct link, something like this:

.../admin/awblog_manage_comment/edit/id/57/

But when I upload the code on the server I receive this link on the e-mail:

.../awblog_manage_comment/edit/id/57/

The admin part is missing and because of that, when I try to reach the link I get a 404 Error.

Can someone tell what is the problem? Is my code or the server, or what else?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You are getting some variables from the config.xml file (Mage::getConfig()->getNode()) and/or core_config_table (Mage::getStoreConfig()). Can you please check it again / edit the question adding at least the file?

Comment: That line of code is working, it returns the 'admin' part from the link on the local, but I just said, the problem is when I upload on the website. config.xml is too big to be added to this post.

Comment: debug this $adminUser variable. Verify what is return in local and what in server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used this code to get admin URL of controller action.

```
$data["url"] = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/awblog_manage_comment/edit/id', array('_secure' => true);
$data["url"] .= $commentId."/";
```

**Note :** 'awblog_manage_comment' replace this, if your admin roughting is diffent, otherwise it working.